# Get first k records / rows of a table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table like that below, how can I get the first `k` rows of it **without using `LIMIT` or `TOP`** ?

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Person | Group | Age |
+--------+-------+-----+
| Bob    | 1     | 32  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
| Jake   | 2     | 29  |
| Paul   | 2     | 36  |
| Laura  | 2     | 39  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

Desired result for `k=3`:

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Bob    | 1     | 32  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

Desired result for `k=4`:

```
+--------+-------+-----+
| Bob    | 1     | 32  |
| Jill   | 1     | 34  |
| Shawn  | 1     | 42  |
| Jake   | 2     | 29  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I need to replicate MySQL's `LIMIT` function without using it.

Comment: Use `where group = 1`.

Comment: What database are you using? And how should the data be ordered?

Comment: Is this a puzzle or do you have some reason why you can't use `LIMIT` or `TOP`?  You could use a cursor to add rows to a temp table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think what he's saying is k is a variable that could be any number. So, k=3 means the first 3 rows, which all happen to have Group=1

Comment: its not about the group id, for example for k=4 it the result should be including :
| Jake   | 2     | 29  |

Comment: What sql database are you using?  SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: @DStanley its an assignment , we are not allowed to use LIMIT and TOP

Comment: @Strawberry Do you have an answer? Although its an assignment, but this question is challenging

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR Yes - but I'm keeping it to myself until the OP demonstrates some effort. (Anyway, it's not as good as the answer already provided )

Comment: @Mohammed Erow: What have you tried on your own? Is your instructor allowing you to get answers from others or is this supposed to be an independent assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. If variables weren't allowed, you could still do it this way...

```
SELECT some, stuff 
  FROM an_instance x 
  JOIN another_instance y 
    ON (y.something < x.something) 
    OR (y.something = x.something AND y.some_other_thing <= x.some_other_thing) 
 GROUP  
    BY x.something,x.some_other_thing
HAVING COUNT(*) <= whatever;
```

...but it would scale appallingly badly on larger data sets.

Comment: Not faith based, I made a typo when copying your query into my editor. My bad. It works, +1.

Comment: I appreciate this answer. Can you please put that in a query shape?

Comment: What is that something?

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR A certain je ne sais quoi

Comment: This answer is upvoted and accepted, which is nice for me. But it's also a pity because jpw's solution is better

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by numbering the rows in a derived table and then selecting the rows with row numbers up until your threshold.

For MySQL the query could look like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS row_number,
            person,
            `group`,
            age
    FROM
        your_table, (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS r
    ORDER BY `group` , age) x
WHERE
    row_number <= 3;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87363/3)

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I was thinking.  I can't really think of another way to do it without using LIMIT.

Comment: @Jim (FWIW, I can think of another way - albeit a slower one!)

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are ordering them first by group number, and then by age. What you can do is select rows in that order, and use a variable to store their position in a list.

Once you have that, you can select rows where the position is less than or equal to your parameter k, like this:

```
SET @position := 0;

SELECT person, groupCol, age
FROM(
  SELECT person, groupCol, age, @position := @position + 1 AS position
  FROM myTable
  ORDER BY groupCol, age) tmp
WHERE tmp.position <= 3;
```